Does presenting at a conference mean having being accepted at it?
I submitted a paper at a conference.
Although the conference website specified that authors would have been notified of acceptance, me and my co-author never got notified (two months have elapsed since the notification deadline, and nothing is to be found in the spam either).
Yet, our paper has been allocated a slot in the presentations.
Does it mean that the paper was accepted?

Which conference management system does your conference use? Easychair?

In the time you wrote your question here, you could just as well have written to the conference organizers :-)

It (showing up on a conference schedule) likely does mean acceptance, but something isn't right. You should contact the committee, say the "Program Chair" for clarification. The most likely explanation is that your acceptance mail went astray, but there are other possibilities. Ask.

I'm curious, what are other possibilities?

In the end the message was indeed not successfully sent.

@Lilla: Planning a conference schedule is complicated, and basically every step is somewhere that an error could occur.  E.g. after acceptance decisions, the programme committee will have made a list of accepted papers in some form, perhaps a spreadsheet of all submissions annotated for acceptance.  One copy then had to go to someone to send emails to authors; another copy had to go to someone to plan the schedule; the two copies may well have been reformatted or prepared separately.  So a name could get accidentally added or dropped in one version by a copy-paste or reformatting error.
